# Laravel DB loses connection (presumably)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a loop where i am getting items from database, currently there are 314 ids in my array and i get the items like so.

```
$s_standards = [];
            $s_sub_category = [];
            foreach ($sanitized_needs['standard'] as $skey => $standard) {
                $sname = DB::table('lesson_observation_teacher_standards')->where('id', $standard)->first()->name;
                $s_standards[] = $sname;
                foreach ($sanitized_needs['sub_category'] as $key => $substandard) {
                $name = DB::table('lesson_observation_teacher_standard_categories')->where('id', $substandard)->first()->name;
                    if ($key == $skey) {
                        $s_sub_category[$sname][] = $name;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I know i could use `WhereIn` but i need the duplicates to calculate the categories.

Both `$santized_needs['standard']` and `$santized_needs['sub_category']` have 314 ids. But when this runs it throws `500 internal server error` but when i comment the queries out and replace them with string it works. My guess is the database is restricting mass queries. There's no error message in both `laravel.log` and network tab in browser.

Is there any way i can disable the restrictions put on database or laravel?

**UPDATE**: Here are some samples of `$sanitized_needs` array.

```
array:2 [
  "standard" => array:312 [
    0 => "C216114B-8751-3874-9154-FC22679569E0"
    1 => "871E5F62-0E1B-3338-969C-2DC4604C8722"
    2 => "B0161059-E9F6-376E-8BB1-B4BF1B10C30F"
    3 => "D1380FB6-37A8-3B3B-B877-A5AF21D9385F"
    4 => "D1380FB6-37A8-3B3B-B877-A5AF21D9385F"
    5 => "676038A6-13D0-32CC-BAD7-A7DA9CFB28EA"
    6 => "D1380FB6-37A8-3B3B-B877-A5AF21D9385F"
    7 => "C216114B-8751-3874-9154-FC22679569E0"
    8 => "676038A6-13D0-32CC-BAD7-A7DA9CFB28EA"
    9 => "676038A6-13D0-32CC-BAD7-A7DA9CFB28EA"
    10 => "C216114B-8751-3874-9154-FC22679569E0"
    ...
  ]
  "sub_category" => array:312 [
    0 => "B2A688A3-1C72-31F4-91CD-6891B5A1D512"
    1 => "5E896BF5-2A99-3059-900A-E1BBBDABF20D"
    2 => "050582A4-003B-3034-A401-040D51A8A751"
    3 => "63ACE688-9F88-3C63-9556-2A291A9C7651"
    4 => "4B8D400E-8160-3D1C-A846-33BA8E93AFB3"
    5 => "7AEE6E97-2F84-3EAA-BC8D-409C6DD48CA3"
    6 => "4B8D400E-8160-3D1C-A846-33BA8E93AFB3"
    7 => "5A878A27-85FC-3FC5-B8FA-70AB7A35D1EB"
    8 => "7AEE6E97-2F84-3EAA-BC8D-409C6DD48CA3"
    9 => "7AEE6E97-2F84-3EAA-BC8D-409C6DD48CA3"
    10 => "596547E6-F3CD-3732-913B-68862898F16C"
    ...
  ]
]
```

Comment: Maybe a typo `sname = DB::table...`?!

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev yeah, sorry

Comment: and what is the 500 internal server error? check the server logs

Comment: @lagbox there's no message to specify the error, absolutely nothing

Comment: and what log files did you check besides the `laravel.log` file?

Comment: @lagbox only that

Comment: so you didn't check the server logs

Comment: @lagbox the server doesn't belong to me but i'll ask the client

Comment: Please note sample array of $santized_needs['standard'] and $santized_needs['sub_category'].

Comment: @DaranyKhiev added it

Comment: I think not $key == $skey, is $standard==$substandard

Comment: @DaranyKhiev no i really check the keys just in case

Comment: did you define "use DB;"

Comment: @DaranyKhiev like this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Comment: Please check spells of table names.

Comment: @DaranyKhiev they are correct

Comment: it is not containing prefix?

Comment: @DaranyKhiev what prefix?

Comment: please try this. you can change 'strict' to false in database.php.

Comment: @DaranyKhiev its already set that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried everything i could ended up changing this part of the code like so

```
$s_standards = [];
$s_sub_category = [];
$all_subs = DB::table('lesson_observation_teacher_standard_categories')->pluck('name','id')->toArray();

            foreach ($sanitized_needs['standard'] as $skey => $standard) {
                $sname = DB::table('lesson_observation_teacher_standards')->where('id', $standard)->first()->name;
                $s_standards[] = $sname;
                foreach ($sanitized_needs['sub_category'] as $key => $substandard) {
                    $name = $all_subs[$substandard];
                    if ($key == $skey) {
                        $s_sub_category[$sname][] = $name;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now i am just preloading the categories and searching them in array.

Now it works fine